# Help with Euler Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a < 0$. Find the following indefinite integral by using the third Euler substitution.

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2) \sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}$$

Where the third Euler substitution is defined by:

Given an integral of the form $\int R(x, \sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c})dx,$ $a \neq 0$.
If the quadratic polynomial under the radical has 2 distinct real roots $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ i.e.,

$$ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-\alpha_1)(x - \alpha_2),$$

then set

$$\sqrt{ax^2 + bx + c} = t(x - \alpha_{1 \text{ or } 2}).$$

Hint: $t^4 + 1 = (t^2 - \sqrt 2t + 1)(t^2 + \sqrt 2t + 1)$.

I tried beginning by setting $$\sqrt{x^2 - a^2} = t(x-a)$$ and attempted to solve for $x$ in order to find some function to define $dx$ in terms of $dt$ but I'm having some trouble. I'm not quite sure how to apply the hint here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ahh, the exponents aren't very legible in the first integral.The denominator is (x^2 + a^2) * sqrt(x^2 - a^2) 
Sorry, I'm new to MathJax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}=t (x+a)$, although I doubt it matters.  In any case, there's just a bunch of algebra to work through:

$$t=\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x+a}} \implies x = a \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$$

$$dx = \frac{4 a t}{(1-t^2)^2} dt$$

$$x^2+a^2 = 2 a^2 \frac{1+t^4}{(1-t^2)^2}$$

$$x^2-a^2 = a^2 \frac{4 t^2}{(1-t^2)^2}$$

so that

$$\begin{align} \int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2) \sqrt{x^2-a^2}} &= \frac{2a}{a^3} \int dt  \frac{t}{(1-t^2)^2} \frac{(1-t^2)^2}{1+t^4} \frac{1-t^2}{2 t}\\ &= \frac{1}{a^2} \int dt \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^4} \end{align}$$

Now put that hint to good use.  Actually, I'll give you a better one:

$$\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^4} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \left ( \frac{2 t + \sqrt{2}}{t^2+\sqrt{2} t+1} - \frac{2 t - \sqrt{2}}{t^2-\sqrt{2} t+1} \right )$$

Note that the fractions are of the form $h'(t)/h(t)$ for some function $h$.

Comment: @ellipsis318: no, you caught an error of mine via transcription.  Glad you are checking this and following through!  I will edit for completeness.

Comment: There's just one thing I'd like to verify. For the step when you find:
$$x^2 + a^2 = a^2\frac{1+t^4}{(1-t^2)^2},$$ I'm getting the same answer just multiplied by 2. i.e, 
$$2a^2\frac{1+t^4}{(1-t^2)^2}$$ 
My process being:
$$x^2 + a^2 = (\frac{a(1+t^2)}{(1-t^2)})^2 + a^2\frac{(1-t^2)^2}{(1-t^2)^2}$$
which gives
$$a^2\frac{(1+2t^2+t^4)+(1-2t^2+t^4)}{(1-t^2)^2} = a^2\frac{2(1+t^4)}{(1-t^2)^2}$$
Am I making some error?

Comment: Okay, thanks again! Writing that comment with proper syntax took a few tries for me, haha.

Comment: Good job on that!

Comment: You use partial fractions after applying the hint, right? Awesome how it turns out to be the perfect format for substitution.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is called.  I provided that last expression because it turned out to be a little trickier than I first thought, and I didn't want to leave you hanging.  Yes, nice how it all worked out, but less surprising given @julien's solution below (which is a much more natural way to evaluate this integral, to be sure; your assignment required that it be done this way, though).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which does not really answer the question, but proposes a way to check the answer.

I recall that in such a situation, the trigonometric substitution
$$
x=a\sec\theta \qquad dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta
$$
could help.

So I tried and I found it yields, after simplification
$$
\frac{1}{a^2}\int\frac{\cos \theta}{2-\sin^2\theta}d\theta.
$$

Now change the variable again with $u=\sin\theta$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{a^2}\int \frac{du}{2-u^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}a^2}\int \left(\frac{1}{u-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{u+\sqrt{2}}\right)du
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4a^2}\log\lvert\frac{u-\sqrt{2}}{u+\sqrt{2}} \rvert +C.
$$

Can I let you substitute back to get functions of $x$?

You can use
$$
\sin \mbox{arcsec}(x/a)=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}{x}
$$
for $x<a<0$.

Comment: The point was to employ that particular substitution.

Comment: @rlgordonma I know, I was just proposing an alternative to double check the answer.